# Mono and MEF Are they compatible.

Tags: mono, mef

The two M's. Are they compatible? I would like to use MEF, or not, depending if it can run in MONO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MEF is included in Mono 2.8 - see http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of Mono includes MEF, I believe, since it was open-sourced:
[Mono 2.8](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8)

I assume that means they're compatible.