# Running MEF on mono

Tags: mono, reference, mef

I tried to compile the MEF code copied from [this page](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Hosting%20MEF%20and%20the%20Container&referringTitle=Guide).

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Reflection;
using System;

public class Program
{
[Import]
public IMessageSender MessageSender { get; set; }

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
 Program p = new Program();
 p.Run();
}

public void Run()
{
 Compose();
 MessageSender.Send("Message Sent");
}

private void Compose()
{
 AssemblyCatalog catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
 var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
 container.ComposeParts(this);
}
}

public interface IMessageSender
{
void Send(string message);
}

[Export(typeof(IMessageSender))]
public class EmailSender : IMessageSender
{
public void Send(string message)
{
 Console.WriteLine(message);
}
}
```

When I run this command `dmcs example.cs` I got this error message.

```
ex.cs(1,29): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Composition' does not exist in the namespace `System.ComponentModel'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

What reference library do I need to give to remove this error message?

### ADDED

`dmcs ex.cs /r:System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll` works. One doesn't have to download the dlls from codeplex.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not MEF is included in Mono isn't the issue, I think ... but that you need the MEF library (not included in Mono libraries). Download the library from [Codeplex](http://mef.codeplex.com/). Then reference it from your project. If that works, then Mono may play nice with it.

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, MEF is not part of Mono at this time. Mono has a "similar" construct with AddIn, but it is not identical to MEF. At this time, creating MEF in Mono would mean rolling your own, unless there is some new magic I am missing out on.

Comment: MEF is a part of mono -> http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909383/mono-and-mef-are-they-compatible

Comment: From my last interaction with Mono, this was the case. Don't look for MEF in Mono - Novell has their own ideas - hmmm, the link @prosseek gave has a link that takes you to the Microsoft MEF page: http://mef.codeplex.com/ on codeplex

Comment: @prosseek: Thanks for the update. Last I had heard, 2.8 was not going to include MEF. Nice to be corrected on something like this. Unfortunately, I have not been on a Mono project recently, so I will accept the correction of my ignorance.