# Can Mono run a WPF, PRISM , MEF, and Unity

Tags: wpf, unity-container, mef, prism-5

Can Mono run a WPF hosted in PRISM 6.o?
Can Mono run the MEF Managed Extensibility Framework?
Can Mono run Unity ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question follow this link which I found by simply googling :

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/wpf/

The very first sentence answers your question :

At this point, no group in the Mono project has plans to implement Windows Presentation Foundation APIs as part of the project.

About mono and MEF see following link :

[Mono and MEF Are they compatible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909383/mono-and-mef-are-they-compatible)

About mono and unity see following link :

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8555/what-is-mono-is-it-a-compiler-a-language-or-what.html